# Saída incorreta em exercício

Tags: c

A saída de dados desse exercício não está correta. Não sei no que errei, se puderem me ajudar agradeço muito

Elabore um programa que leia 10 números inteiros e armazene em um vetor. Depois de preenchido o vetor, imprima somente os números pares do vetor:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    int veto [10];
    int par [10];
    int j = 0;
    int n;
    printf("Digite 10 numeros para identificar se sao pares ou nao\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        scanf("%i", &veto[i]);
        if (veto[i] % 2 == 0)
        {
            par[j] = veto[i];
            j++;
            n = j;
        }
    }

    for (; n > 0; n--)
    {
        printf("Os numeros pares sao %i", par[n]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Coloque um exemplo de entrada e a saída. E o último loop deveria ser n>=0 no lugar de n>0

Comment: Inverta os comandos ` j++; n = j;` para `n = j;  j++;`, dessa forma `n` indicará o último elemento, e em `for (; n > 0; n--)` utilize `n >= 0`, pois o índice 0 é o índice do primeiro elemento do vetor.

Answer (score 2):

Seu problema está no ultimo laço de repetição, tente fazer desta forma:

```c
for (int i = n-1; i >= 0; i--){
    printf("Os numeros pares sao %i\n", par[i]);
}
```

Eu coloquei `i = n-1` pois dá 9 (o vetor tem 10 posições mas começa no 0) e vai até o 0 que é a primeira posição.